# Invalid JSON object when posting to an API - Python

Tags: python, json, api

I am using `Blockchain.info's` `API` to send multiple payments. I believe I have everything how it should be however when I run the code I get the following Error: RuntimeError: ERROR: Invalid Recipients `JSON`. Please make sure it is `url` encoded and consult the docs. The docs can be found here: https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api

The `Python library` I am using can be found here: https://github.com/p4u/blockchain.py/blob/master/blockchain.py

The only other post on this issue is posted by the original creator of the library, he said the problem was that the amounts cannot be a decimal, mine are not however.Post can be found here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=600870.0

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from itertools import islice, imap
import csv, requests, json, math
from collections import defaultdict
import requests
import urllib
import json
from os.path import expanduser
import configparser


class Wallet: 
    guid        = 'g'
    isAccount   = 0
    isKey       = 0
    password1   = 'x'
    password2   = 'y'
    url         = ''

def __init__(self, guid = 'g', password1 = 'x', password2 = 'y'):

    if guid.count('-') > 0:
        self.isAccount = 1
        if password1 == '': # wallet guid's contain - 
            raise ValueError('No password with guid.')
    else:
        self.isKey = 1

    self.guid = guid
    self.url = 'https://blockchain.info/merchant/' + guid + '/'

    self.password1 = password1
    self.password2 = password2

    r = requests.get('http://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/addrs/A/balance')
    balance = r.json()['balance']

    with open("Entries#x1.csv") as f,open("winningnumbers.csv") as nums:
        nums = set(imap(str.rstrip, nums))
        r = csv.reader(f)
        results = defaultdict(list)
        for row in r:
            results[sum(n in nums for n in islice(row, 1, None))].append(row[0])

    self.number_matched_0 = results[0]
    self.number_matched_1 = results[1]
    self.number_matched_2 = results[2]
    self.number_matched_3 = results[3]
    self.number_matched_4 = results[4]
    self.number_matched_5 = results[5]

    self.number_matched_5_json = json.dumps(self.number_matched_5, sort_keys = True, indent = 4)

    print(self.number_matched_5_json)

    if len(self.number_matched_3) == 0:
        print('Nobody matched 3 numbers')
    else:
        self.tx_amount_3 = int((balance*0.001)/ len(self.number_matched_3))

    if len(self.number_matched_4) == 0:
        print('Nobody matched 4 numbers')
    else:
        self.tx_amount_4 = int((balance*0.1)/ len(self.number_matched_4))

    if len(self.number_matched_5) == 0:
        print('Nobody matched 3 numbers')
    else:
        self.tx_amount_5 = int((balance*0.4)/ len(self.number_matched_5))

    self.d = {el: self.tx_amount_5 for el in json.loads(self.number_matched_5_json)}
    print(self.d)

    self.d_url_enc = urllib.urlencode(self.d)

def Call(self, method, data = {}):
    if self.password1 != '':
        data['password'] = self.password1 
    if self.password2 != '':
        data['second_password'] = self.password2

    response = requests.post(self.url + method,params=data)

    json = response.json()
    if 'error' in json:
        raise RuntimeError('ERROR: ' + json['error'])

    return json

def SendPayment(self, toaddr, amount, fromaddr = 'A', shared = 0, fee = 0.0001, note = True):
    data = {}
    data['to'] = toaddr
    data['amount'] = self.tx_amount_5
    data['fee'] = fee
    data['recipients'] = self.d_url_enc

    if fromaddr:
        data['from'] = fromaddr

    if shared:
        data['shared'] = 'true'

    if note:
        data['note'] = 'n'

    response = self.Call('payment',data)

def SendManyPayment(self, fromaddr = True, shared = False, fee = 0.0001, note = True):
    data = {}
    recipients = self.d_url_enc
    data['recipients'] = recipients.__str__().replace("'",'"')
    data['fee'] = str(fee)
    if fromaddr:
        data['from'] = 'A'
    if shared:
        data['shared'] = 'true'
    else:
        data['shared'] = 'false'
    if note:
        data['note'] = 'n'
    response = self.Call('sendmany',data)

    return response

print(Wallet().SendManyPayment())


Complete runtime error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Documents\B\Code\A\jsontest.py", line 125, in <module>
    print(Wallet().SendManyPayment())
  File "D:\Documents\B\Code\A\jsontest.py", line 121, in SendManyPayment
    response = self.Call('sendmany',data)
  File "D:\Documents\B\Code\A\jsontest.py", line 86, in Call
    raise RuntimeError('ERROR: ' + json['error'])
RuntimeError: ERROR: Invalid Recipients JSON. Please make sure it is url encoded and consult the docs.
```

Comment: Show the whole traceback.

Comment: Added the complete traceback to the end of the code.

Comment: @ekhumoro Do you have any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `data['recipients']` contain inside of your `SendManyPayment()` function? It looks like you are trying to do some manual encoding instead of using `json.dumps(recipients)`

The docs say it should look like this:

```
{
    "1JzSZFs2DQke2B3S4pBxaNaMzzVZaG4Cqh": 100000000,
    "12Cf6nCcRtKERh9cQm3Z29c9MWvQuFSxvT": 1500000000,
    "1dice6YgEVBf88erBFra9BHf6ZMoyvG88": 200000000
}
```

Try this out for send many:

```
def SendManyPayment(self, fromaddr = True, shared = False, fee = 0.0001, note = True):
    data = {}
    recipients = self.d_url_enc
    # recipients should be a json string FIRST!
    data['recipients'] = json.dumps(recipients)
    data['fee'] = str(fee)
    if fromaddr:
        data['from'] = 'A'
    if shared:
        data['shared'] = 'true'
    else:
        data['shared'] = 'false'
    if note:
        data['note'] = 'n'
    response = self.Call('sendmany',data)

    return response
```

Comment: My JSON code looks like this `{u'35xfg4UnpEJeHDo55HNwJbr1V3G1ddCuVA': 543859, u'3D3iAR9M4HDETajfD79gs9BM8qhMSq5izX': 543859}`

Comment: The URL encoded version looks like this: `35xfg4UnpEJeHDo55HNwJbr1V3G1ddCuVA=543859&3D3iAR9M4HDETajfD79gs9BM8qhMSq5izX=543859`                                                                judging from the docs this is what I should be posting.

Comment: That isn't `json` code, that is a `dict`. Then it is being url encoded as multiple parameters instead of json data urlencoded. You need to turn `recipients` into a `json` string and **then** assign it to `data['recipients']`.

Comment: Perfect thankyou, I am new to JSON so I wasnt to sure at first. This really helped thanks man!

Comment: You are welcome. I figured there was a disconnect on the json encoding part. Their api is also strange in that it wants form data with some of the items containing json data.